# Is it possible to check when private members access our Google Site?

Tags: web

I have created a private Google Site for a university project and I only assigned several people to be able to access to this site. The thing is I want to know who actually comes in, access the site. Is it possible?

Comment: This seems like a question for [Web Apps](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/), actually - but certainly not here (unless it's about programming in some way I'm not seeing).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google doesn't release any identifying information to Gadgets, which to my knowledge, is the only way to put some of your own code on a Google Sites page.  Unless there is a built-in method, I doubt this possible.  As David suggested, check https://webapps.stackexchange.com/ for information on what built-in functionality that may exist.